# unable to select highlighted text in jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextarea

I have highlighted some text in the JTextArea, but i am unable to select the highlight **manually**. How could i do this?

```
jTextArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(0,5);
jTextArea.getHighlighter().removeHighlight(jTextArea.getSelectionStart(),jTextArea.getSelectionEnd());
```

When i am trying to remove the highlight that is selected by the user, the selection start and end are being shown as one and the same and therefore the selected text (textArea.getSelectedText()) is null.

I want to remove the highlight that is selected by the user.

When i select it using the keyboard, it has to get selected. Does it? And one more thing is that the highlight should not be removed when the text is selected.

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: What is selectionStart and selectionEnd.? How are you storing values in it? Would be much better if you put the code which could be executed..

Comment: How are you detecting selection changes?

Comment: `jTextAra.getSelectionEnd()` and `jTextAra.getSeletionStart()` won't work in this case..Look at David's example given below..

Answer (score 7):

Grrr I found an easier solution, rather use `SimpleAttributeSet` of `JTextPane` `StyledDocument`.

The magic happens at: `StyleConstants.setBackground(sas, Color.RED);` could also be `setForeground(..)`.

Than if we select text, it applies the *internal highlighter* which we see covering our highlighted text (Image 2) - which was done at document level, thus not interfering with user selection highlighter which the `JTextPane` uses by default - completely.

Check here:

When app starts:

[image]

after I have selected text:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class HighlightTest {

    String[] words = new String[]{"world", "cruel"};
    int[] wordsStartPos = new int[]{6, 21};
    String text = "Hello world, Goodbye cruel world";

    public HighlightTest() {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                JTextPane jta = new JTextPane();

                jta.setText(text);

                SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                StyleConstants.setBackground(sas, Color.RED);
                StyledDocument doc = jta.getStyledDocument();

                for (int i = 0; i < wordsStartPos.length; i++) {
                    doc.setCharacterAttributes(wordsStartPos[i], words[i].length(), sas, false);
                }
                frame.add(jta);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HighlightTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to select the highlighted text without removing the highlight on the selected text. Thanks for the code.

Comment: @JavaTechnical and? have you tested/looked at my code? simply change the `removeSelectedTextHighlightes(..)` `to String text= textComp.getSelectedText();
        System.out.println(text);` and it should ouput to you the selected text (of course remove the code which delets highlights if you dont want that.

Comment: No i don't want to print it. I've looked at your code. What i mean is that i am unable to see the selection on the highlighted text. This is what is my problem. The selection background is not appearing when i am selecting the highlighted text. As a result, the user could not detect whether the text is selected.

Comment: @JavaTechnical well than you will have to change the highlight color of the selected word as it is selected. I will look into updating the code, just busy with supper right now

Comment: @JavaTechnical `JTextArea` was not meant for this. As per docs: A *JTextArea is a multi-line area that displays **plain text**.* So unless you want to go reinveting the wheel, i.e creating your own custom `StyledDocument`, just go for `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane`.

Comment: OK. Is there any alternative way? I am disappointed :( Your program is working fine any ways! :)